# SQL-Full of the duplicated data need to be removed

Tags: sql, database, firebase-realtime-database, google-bigquery

**I have question regarding removing duplicated values in excel table.**
The condition is splitting the dataset into date and time intervals and updating some tables based on the latest insert data date and other tables based on the first update.

As shown in the below example, I need to split the dataset based on date and remove all duplicates by only keeping the oldest date rows.And in the second time interval, remove all duplicates by only keeping the most recent ones (it's the same dataset).
=> output should be like this

F.ex:

The current dataset

```
|date      |amount | update_date|
|----------|-------|------------|      
|01-01-2023|13     | 01-01-2023 |
|01-01-2023|13     | 01-02-2023 |         
|01-01-2023|13     | 01-03-2023           
|01-01-2023|13     | 01-04-2023 
|          |       |
|01-02-2023|14     | 01-05-2023    
|01-02-2023|14     | 01-05-2023    
|01-02-2023|14     | 01-05-2023    
|01-02-2023|14     | 01-05-2023
   .                    .    
   .                    .    
|01-10-2023 |13     |01-10-2023    
|01-10-2023 |13     |01-10-2023   
|01-10-2023 |13     |01-10-2023    
|01-10-2023 |13     |01-10-2023    
|01-10-2023 |14     |01-10-2023  
|           |       |
|02-10-2023 |14     |01-11-2023    
|02-10-2023 |14     |01-11-2023    
|02-10-2023 |15     |01-11-2023    
   .                    .    
   .                    .
```

The version I like to have

```
|01-01-2023 |13     |01-01-2023   
|01-02-2023 |14     |01-05-2023    
|01-10-2023 |14     |01-10-2023    
|02-10-2023 |15     |01-11-2023
```

I have try to split dataset by using where date between ="...." and
"....."
but it didn't work out.

Comment: Thx for the response, due to a technical problem I cannot run the code now. I will inform you whenever I can.

Comment: Regarding, *"I have try to split dataset by using where date between ="...." and "....." but it didn't work out."* -- please show exactly what you've tried, what result you expected vs what was observed, what debugging you've done,... all to help improve this question.

Comment: The code didn't even complete.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the most recent ones

you can use

```
SELECT
    MIN(date),       amount,  MIN(update_date) update_date
FROM yourtable
WHERE date BETWEEn 01-01-2023 AND 01-03-2023
GROUP BY amount
```

But in your sample result you show the oldest update_date, then you would use `MIN`

Comment: Thx for the respond, I guess I wasnt clear enough with the question.

Comment: then please explain better what you mean, my query delivers the exact sample result that you wanted

Comment: Thx for the response, I guess I wasn't clear enough with the question.                                                   1-I would like to get the date from  01-01-2023 to 01-03-2023 and remove all duplicated date columns by using the update_date column to keep the most recent data.

Comment: you can simple add  a WHERE clause like in the change code and still you would get the right answer

Comment: No, it didn't update it. Actually didn't do anything at all :(

Comment: sorry i can't understand your sample data, and the wanted result.  why is |01-02-2023|15     | 01-05-2023 not in your result or |01-10-2023 |13     |01-10-2023   and so on why onöy those 4, the rest can't be a duplicate

Comment: I do not need to get a result, I just need to split data into date time such that from 01-05-2023 to 05-05-2023 and remove all duplicated values and keep only the most recent data based on the update_date column. My database fetches data daily and I just need to keep the latest dataset within a given specific timeline.

Comment: Regarding sampe, As it shown in table the first column keep the first entries and the last 2 keep only the latest insert data in the same table.

Comment: and how should a alghorithm now why 13 is only the first and for the first 14 also the first. which is the logic behind this the numers 13-15 means nothing to an alghorithm, you need a additional column that makes 13 as only the first 14 last and first and 15 last only

Comment: I have updated it. It was a mistake sorry for that. The logic as I explain before split the dataset and get the oldest version of it on the first proportion of the dataset and remove the rest, then on the second portion of the data remove all the oldest and keep only new inserted dataset based on the update_date column.

Comment: to simplify it tables are by nature unsorted ther is no upper first or last row, for amount  must be a logic as an Alghorithm, which can determine what is what